# Problemas com a instalação do pacote SSOAP no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando instalar o pacote `SSOAP` no software `R` e recebo como retorno a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ERROR: dependency 'XMLSchema' is not available for package 'SSOAP'
>   * removing '\srvfcmfile/documentos$/2437/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6/SSOAP'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/2437/Desktop/FORMAO~1/MACROE~1/61E21~1.MOD/SSOAP_0.9-0(1).tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Pesquisei a respeito do erro e do pacote e pelo que entendi este foi removido.

A parte de código que estou tentando rodar é essa:

```
wsdl <- getURL("https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl", 
           ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
doc  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(wsdl)

def <- processWSDL(doc)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def)
```

`processWSDL` e `genSOAPClientInterface` dependem de `SSOAP`.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum outro pacote que substitui o `SSOAP` para que eu possa conseguir rodar o que preciso.

Comment: Pode is buscar o pacote XMLSchema aos [arquivos CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/XMLSchema/) ou ao [Omegahat](http://www.omegahat.net/XMLSchema/) (o link está no número de versão).

Comment: @RuiBarradas O pacote XMLSchema eu já havia tentando instalar anteriormente, e ele retorna erro também.

Comment: Feito, veja a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar pacotes R que não estão disponíveis para a versão do R que está a correr, deve-se ir ver se estão nos [arquivos do CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/).

Depois há várias maneiras de instalar esses pacotes. Vou assumir que o usuário baixou os arquivos `.tar.gz` dos arquivos e que estes se encontram em um directório local.

O seguinte funciona em Ubuntu 19.04.

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd('~/um/caminho/para/as/transferencias')

file_xmlschema <- list.files(pattern = '^XMLSchema_.*\\.tar\\.gz')
install.packages(file_xmlschema, repos = NULL, type = "source")

file_ssoap <- list.files(pattern = '^SSOAP_.*\\.tar\\.gz')
install.packages(file_ssoap, repos = NULL, type = "source")

setwd(old_dir)
```

Pronto, os pacotes estão instalados. Agora vou correr o código da pergunta.

```
library(SSOAP)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

wsdl <- getURL("https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl", 
               ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
doc  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(wsdl)

def <- processWSDL(doc)
```

> There were 12 warnings (use `warnings()` to see them)

Todas as mensagens de aviso são idênticas. Significam que o código da função deveria ser atualizado de modo a prever uma lista sem elementos.

```
warnings()
```

> Mensagens de aviso:
>   1: In structure(unlist(v[i]), names = sapply(v[i], names)) :
>     Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
>     Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.

```
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def)
```

Comment: os pacotes não instalaram da mesma forma. Como atualizar o código da função? As vezes é possível realizar a mesma operação utilizando outro pacote.

Comment: @LetíciaMarrara Se diz que *os pacotes não instalaram*, o problema não está na função, deve estar nas instruções que usou para instalar os pacotes. Pode editar **a pergunta** com o código usado para isso?

Comment: O pacote SSOAP está instalando normalmente na sua máquina?

Comment: @LetíciaMarrara Sim, está. Tal e qual disse na resposta.

Comment: Acredito que o problema está aí então. Pq na minha máquina não instala. Ou você encontrou algum outro problema no código?

Comment: @LetíciaMarrara Quando corre o primeiro `install.packages` da minha resposta dá erro? Se sim qual?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(XML)

library(RCurl)

old_dir <- getwd()
setwd('~/um/caminho/para/as/transferencias') #adicionei aqui o diretório utilizado, conforme me explicou acima.

file_xmlschema <- list.files(pattern = '^XMLSchema_.*\\.tar\\.gz')
install.packages(file_xmlschema, repos = NULL, type = "source")

file_ssoap <- list.files(pattern = '^SSOAP_.*\\.tar\\.gz')
install.packages(file_ssoap, repos = NULL, type = "source")

setwd(old_dir)

wsdl <- getURL("https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl", 
               ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
doc  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(wsdl)

def <- processWSDL(doc)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def)

inicio <- '01/01/1999'

fim <- '04/09/2015'

getSeries <- function(codigos, data.ini = inicio, data.fim = fim, remove.old = TRUE) {
  xmlstr <- ff@functions$getValoresSeriesXML(codigos, data.ini, data.fim, 
                                             .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
  doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(xmlstr)

  cleanup <- xpathApply(doc,"//SERIE", function(s) {
    id <- xmlGetAttr(s, "ID")
    s1 <- xmlSApply(s, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
    s1 <- t(s1)
    dimnames(s1) <- list(NULL, dimnames(s1)[[2]])
    df <- as.data.frame(s1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df$SERIE <- id
    df
  })
  df <- Reduce(rbind, cleanup)

  df$data  <- as.Date(sapply(strsplit(df$DATA,  "/"),
                             function(x) paste(c(x[2:1], 1), collapse="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
  df$valor <- as.numeric(df$VALOR)
  df$serie <- factor(df$SERIE)

  if(remove.old){
    df$BLOQUEADO <- NULL
    df$SERIE <- NULL
    df$DATA <- NULL
    df$VALOR <- NULL
  }
  df
}
```

Este é o código que preciso rodar.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro

- installing *source* package 'XMLSchema' ...
  ** package 'XMLSchema' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'XMLSchema'
  Calls:  -> findpack
  Execução interrompida
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'XMLSchema'
- removing '\srvfcmfile/documentos$/2437/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6/XMLSchema'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XMLSchema_0.6-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'XMLSchema' ...
  ** package 'XMLSchema' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'XMLSchema'
  Calls:  -> findpack
  Execução interrompida
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'XMLSchema'
- removing '\srvfcmfile/documentos$/2437/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6/XMLSchema'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XMLSchema_0.7-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: @RuiBarradas este é o erro que aparece

Comment: Qual é o sistema operacional? Se for o Windows precisa do [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) instalado para compilar o código fonte.